# Magento store views inflated database

Tags: magento-1.9, database, multistore, store-view

When adding store views to Magento it creates rather large tables because it adds an entry for each storeview * each product in the following tables:

```
core_url_rewrite  
catalog_product_index_eav_idx   
catalog_product_index_eav  
catalog_category_product_index  
catalogsearch_fulltext
```

But what if in the setup that i'm using this data will be identical across all store views, is there a way to stop Magento from creating all these tables?
The only thing we want is to have a different {base_url} for each storeview, the catalog will be the EXACT same across all storeviews.

What I'm asking in other words is: can we create a module to create new store views that only have the functionality of assigning a base_url to a store view without all the index and catalog tables that get added

Comment: Still too broad: Your question is clear but the answer is that you would need to rewrite half of Magento.

Comment: @fschmengler Thank you, I realize that. do you have any better suggestions or can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this cannot happen. Magento creates separate table for each store view and will work according to that only.

Comment: i know that's how Magento works - i';m trying to figure out how to get around that